# At what point a battery becomes a load

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, amperage, watts

This has probably been asked before but I don't know how to search for it.

In a circuit where there are a battery and a variable power supply, what conditions have to be met in order for the battery to turn into a load rather than a current/voltage source and start receiving charge from the power supply?

Comment: \$ V_{PSU} > V_{batt} \$.

Comment: @Transistor and generally also source impedance R(Psu) < R(batt load) right? If you model both psu and batt as ideal voltage sources it can’t be done. Psu should always have low Source impedance, but batt source impedance depends on state of charge and other factors.

Comment: Generally, yes, but I've seen simple battery charger circuits for AA NiCd cells which provided a safe continuous trickle charge from a high voltage source via a high value resistor- much higher than the cell's internal resistance.

Comment: @MarkU Not necessarily : famously NiCds require constant current charging' when Rpsu approximates infinity.

Comment: In order to calculate the charge current, the source impedance and battery ESR must be known. But it is still true that the battery transitions from being a source to a load precisely when Vpsu > Vbatt (assuming Vpsu is the actual output voltage of the supply).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simply \$ V_{PSU} > V_{batt} \$.

When this is true power will flow from the power supply to the battery.

When \$ V_{PSU} < V_{batt} \$ then the battery will take over. Whether current flows from the battery into the power supply depends on the PSU design. Generally it will not as the output diodes prevent it.

Where PSU and batteries are connected care has to be taken in the design to prevent over-voltage and over-current conditions which may damage, destroy or explode the batteries.